# Gradient Descent in ReLU Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, activation-function

I’m new to machine learning and recently facing a problem on back propagation of training a neural network using ReLU activation function shown in the figure. My problem is to update the weights matrices in the hidden and output layers.

The cost function is given as:

$J(\Theta) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{2} \left(a_i^{(3)} - y_i\right)^2$

where $y_i$ is the $i$-th output from output layer.

[image]

Using the gradient descent algorithm, the weights matrices can be updated by:

$\Theta_{jk}^{(2)} := \Theta_{jk}^{(2)} - \alpha\frac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial \Theta_{jk}^{(2)}}$

$\Theta_{ij}^{(3)} := \Theta_{ij}^{(3)} - \alpha\frac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial \Theta_{ij}^{(3)}}$

I understand how to update the weight matrix at output layer $\Theta_{ij}^{(3)}$, however I don’t know how to update that from the input layer to hidden layer $\Theta_{jk}^{(2)}$ involving the ReLU activation units, i.e. not understanding how to get $\frac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial \Theta_{jk}^{(2)}}$.

Can anyone help me understand how to derive the gradient on the cost function...?

Comment: if you found the solution .. can u please share it with us  ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post. I found it quite useful when starting out with neural networks.

http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html

Comment: Thanks for your reference! That helps with a clearer picture of understanding, particularly for the calculus part.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a ReLU is:

$$\frac{\partial ReLU(x)}{\partial x}
=
\begin{cases} 
0 & \text{if  }  x < 0 \\
1 & \text{if  }  x > 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

So its value is set either to 0 or 1. It's not defined at 0, there must be a convention to set it either at 0 or 1 in this case.

To my understanding, it means that the error is either fully propagated to the previous layer (1), or completely stopped (0).

Comment: I understand the special derivative for the ReLU function. But sorry for the unclear of my question that I want to understand the calculus part of the partial derivative, i.e. $\frac{\partial J(\Theta)}{\partial \Theta_{ij}^{(x)}}$, for some $x$-th layers $i$ and $j$. Thanks anyway!

Comment: maybe late, but this means that if we have a single final neuron that uses relu, if it predict 0, there is no "error propagation", since for backprop we always multiply by the derivative of the activation?